# Angular $timeout doesn't update the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my controller I have a method that sends a POST request to my REST API. On success/error I want to display an success/error message using `ng-show`. The problem is that my scope variable is changed but my view is not being updated.
I have tried using `$scope.$apply()` but that throws `$digest` error.
Below is my current code. Any ideas?

```
 function AdminController($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.addUserError = false;
    $scope.addUserSuccess = false;

    $scope.createUser = function (newuser) {
        $http.post("rest/user", JSON.stringify(newuser)).success(function () {
            console.log("User added");
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.addUserSuccess = true;
                $scope.addUserError = false;
            });
        }).error(function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.addUserSuccess = false;
                $scope.addUserError = true;
                console.log($scope.addUserError); //true
            });
        })
    }
    }
```

Comment: You dont need `timeout` - `$http` will trip a `$digest` cycle - are there any errors in your call?

Comment: One of the tenants of angular is to always put your properties in an object under $scope. So instead of `$scope.addUserSuccess` you'd have `$scope.model.addUserSuccess`. Sometimes this is all you need to fix something like this.

Comment: @tymeJV no errors. I put `error {{addUserError}}<br>
success {{addUserSuccess}}`. It is being shown correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code to the following:

```
function AdminController($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.addUserError = false;
    $scope.addUserSuccess = false;

    $scope.createUser = function (newuser) {
        $http.post("rest/user", JSON.stringify(newuser)).success(function () {
            $scope.addUserSuccess = true;
            $scope.addUserError = false;
        }).error(function () {
            $scope.addUserSuccess = false;
            $scope.addUserError = true;
        });
    };
}
```

Your view should look something like this:

```
<div ng-show="addUserSuccess">User Added!</div>
<div ng-show="addUserError">Error adding user</div>
```

You don't need to use timeout here.  This is just a simple model update and angular will do this for you inside the $http call automatically.

Comment: You and tymeJV were both correct. Although my error was also that I had `ng-show={{addUserSuccess}}`. Thank you!